# pandas date conversion error from string to epoch time

Tags: pandas

I have the code snippet as follows:

```
import time
now = time.time()
evt_time='2022-10-20T04:10:36Z'
diff_time = now - pd.to_datetime(evt_time, unit='s')
```

This results in an error. Primarily because the `now` is in epoch time and the `evt_time` needs to be converted.
How do I achieve this conversion? I need the result in epoch time...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Timestamp.timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.timestamp.html) to convert to epoch:

```
import time
now = time.time()
evt_time = '2022-10-20T04:10:36Z'
diff_time = now - pd.Timestamp(evt_time).timestamp()
diff_time
```

example output: `157054.39800930023`

Comment: Thanks @mozway...I wonder if there is a non-pandas way of doing this? As this piece of code will execute in AWS Lambda and I just realized pandas seems to be not supported out of box in there...Thanks again!